# Python code to check for keyword in page title suceeds but fails for meta description

Tags: python, seo

I have a Python code that checks if a given keyword occurs in an URL's page title and meta description.

The check works fine for the page title, but returns nothing for the meta description. It treats them as if no meta description is present:

[image: See Output]

Can someone point me in the right direction? I use Google Colab and am just getting started in Python.

**Code:**

````
from urllib.request import urlopen
!pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

## URL and Keyword input

url = input("Which site should be checked? Input URL: ")
keyword = input("Which keyword should be checked? ")
keyword = keyword.casefold()

## URL query
try:
    html = urlopen(url)
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e)

## parse HTML
data = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

## displaying the title
title = data.find('title')
print("URL Title Tag: ")
print(title.string)

## displaying the description
metas = data.find('meta',attrs={'name':'description'})["content"]
print("URL Meta Description: ")
print(metas)

## Keyword in Title?

def seo_title_found(keyword, data):                 
    if data.title:                                 
        if keyword in data.title.text.casefold(): 
            status = "Keyword is used in the Meta Title."
        else:
            status = "Keyword is not used in the Meta Title."
    else:
        status = "No Meta Title found."

    return status

## Keyword in Meta Description?

def seo_meta_found(keyword, data):
    if metas:
        if keyword in metas.casefold():
          status = "Keyword is used in the Meta Description."
        else:
          status = "Keyword is not used in the Meta Description."
    else:
        status = "No Meta Description found."

    return status

## SEO Title Length

def seo_title_length(data):
  if data.title:
    if len(data.title.text) < 60:
      length = "Title length is below the recommended threshold of 60 characters. (Number of characters: {}.)".format(len(data.title.text))
    else:
        length = "Title length is over 60 characters."
  else:
    length = "No Title found."
  
  return length

## Meta Description Length

def seo_meta_length(data):
  if metas:
    if len(metas) < 148:
      meta_length = "Meta Description length is below the recommended maximum of 148 characters (Number of characters: {}.)".format(len(data.meta.text))
    else:
      meta_length = "Meta Description length is over 148 characters."
  else:
    meta_length = "No Meta Description found."

  return meta_length

print(seo_title_found(keyword, data))
print(seo_title_length(data))
print(seo_meta_found(keyword, data))
print(seo_meta_length(data))```
````

Comment: There is no such thing as a "meta title." The page title uses the `<title>` tag which is separate from `<meta>` tags. Furthermore, unlike meta information about the page, the page title is visible to users in the browser tab and title bar. I've edited your question to correct the terminology.

Comment: You define variables for `title` and `metas` but I can't see where your code uses them after that.  How are they supposed to get into your functions?

Comment: Hi Stephen, I edited the **metas** part of my code, using the defined variable (see above). I can now correctly check for keyword occurrence in the meta description, but the code is still not counting the number of characters used in the description.